# React Native Date Range

Tags: react-native, date-range

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { globalStyles } from "../styles/global";
import {Calendar, CalendarList, Agenda} from 'react-native-calendars';
import {LocaleConfig} from 'react-native-calendars';
import  moment  from  "moment";
import DateRangePicker from "react-native-daterange-picker";

export default function About(){
    const [endDate, setendDate] = useState(null)
    const [startDate, setstartDate] = useState(null)
    const [displayedDate, setdisplayedDate] = useState(moment())

    state = {
        endDate: null,
        startDate: null,
        displayedDate: moment()
    };

    const handleSubmit = (props) => {

        console.log(props);
        setendDate(props.endDate);
        setstartDate(props.startDate);
        setdisplayedDate(props.displayedDate);
        // console.log(props.startDate);
        // console.log(props.displayedDate);
    }

    return(
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>

        <DateRangePicker
          onChange={ handleSubmit }
          endDate={endDate}
          startDate={startDate}
          displayedDate={displayedDate}
          range>
          <Text>Click me!</Text>
          </DateRangePicker>

        </View>
    )
}
```

1.not able to select date range.
2. undefined is not an object (evaluating displayedDate.format)
3. Using function component but most of the solutions are available with class component

Comment: changed some code

Comment: Error 2. is telling you that it is unable to evaluate `displayedDate.format` this tells you that it is trying to use a moment method on a string.

Try this.
```setdisplayedDate(moment(props.displayedDate));```

For the rest. I'm on the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

You can call handleSubmit as follows
onChang={() => handleSubmit()}

And props param is needless in function prototype
const handleSubmit = (props) => {}
Because props is already declared and you don't need to set it as parameter.
If you want to use it as parameter then you should change like this
onChange={() => handleSubmit(props)}

Hope this helps you.

Comment: still not working.... i think i am doing some mistake to setting values of endDate, startDate and displayedDate

Comment: moment default format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ. So please check the date variables are formatted as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your  `handleSubmit()` function like this

```
const handleSubmit = (props) => {
  if (props.startDate != undefined) {
    setStartDate(props.startDate);
  }

  if (props.displayedDate != undefined) {
    setDisplayedDate(props.displayedDate);
  }

  if (props.endDate != undefined) {
    setEndDate(props.endDate);
  }
 }
```

Source: [issues#15](https://github.com/Naxulanth/react-native-daterange-picker/issues/15)